# 特徴ある建物の場所に印（ラベル）をつけたい

Tags: google-maps

Google Mapsで特徴ある建物を目で確認しているのですが
効率的に行うため、自動化したいと考えています。

どのようなAPI等使用するのが良いでしょうか？
Google Mapsで場合、他の地図アプリ、サービス等
ご紹介いただけると助かります。

Comment: > `特徴ある建物` とは、どのようなものを指していますか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。特徴ある建物とは住宅の屋根にある太陽光パネルです。